# How can i download a report using wget

Tags: wget

I am trying to use WGET to automate download of a file which is generated by a report server (PDF format). However, the problem i am having is that the file name is never known (generated randomly by the server) and the URL accepts parameters that will change eg. Date=. Name= ID= etc.

For Example if i were to pass http://url.com/date=&name=&id= in internet explorer, i will get a download dialog prompting me to download a file with file xyz123.pdf

Is it possible that i can use WGET to pass these parameters to the report server and automatically download the generated PDF file

Comment: Can you not just use the same URL as you do in your browser?

Comment: So how do you determine the values for the three parameters when you're dealing with the page interactively?

Comment: The page allows you to set the options in the form of combo boxes and textboxes. I cannot use the same URL from the browser because it information will change. For eg. Lets say i want to run it for 200 users, that will be 200 different ID fields to set

Comment: Could you algorithmically set the parameters? Is there a pattern to them?

Comment: Yeh, i have written a script that will read a text file with each ID etc and generate the url with each parameter inserted. I actually have a working version of it where i automated an Internet Explorer browser. However, I was thinking that WGET might be faster than automating an IE browser instance

Answer (score 0):

Just put the full url in quotes - It should go and fetch the file:

```
   wget "http://url.com/date=foo&name=baa&id=baz"
```

Thanks,
//P

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. Do you have Any other suggestions?

Comment: Got a test link we can play with?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is an intranet site so you wont be able to reach it.

Comment: Makes things a bit more difficult bt not impossible - I won't go asking for VPN creds now ;-) - Seen and will try and get back to you ASAP

Comment: Also - Silly off the top of my head does:
   wget --content-disposition
    or
   curl -J -O 

Do anything of interest?

Comment: Ok this one has got to me - largely due to the blind work on it ;-)
I had a read of this: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2007/09/15/use-wget-or-curl-to-download-from-rapidshare-premium/

wget -c --load-cookies ~/.cookies/rapidshare <URL>

and

curl -L -O --cookie ~/.cookies/rapidshare <URL>

look promising ;-) happy tapping :P

Comment: wget  --content-disposition, does not seem to work. Thanks again though..keep the ideas coming ;-)